# Windows Phone 8 Emulator on Azure VM

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8

I've done a lot of research and it's apparent that the Windows 8 emulator cannot be run inside an Azure VM.  I've seen the the answers provided in similar questions on SO, but I haven't seen anyone propose these solutions so it's worth a shot.

In one article I read, the guy claimed he was able to use USB pass-through to connect his physical phone to the virtual machine but I haven't been able to get that to work.  I'm starting to suspect that he was using a local VM and not connecting via RDP to an Azure VM.  If anyone has more information about whether this should work, please pass it on.

I have two ideas for workarounds, but I'm not sure if they'd work so I'm looking for some input in case I'm just wasting my time.

1) The emulator VM could be run as a standalone device in my Azure domain.  I don't think this is possible without some help from Microsoft.  I haven't looked into this very far, but it doesn't appear that I can upload my own VM to Azure.  My assumption is that MS would need to provide the emulator VM image in the gallery.

2) I'm slightly more optimistic about this one, but once again, I'm making a lot of assumptions based on very little knowledge.  I have seen that's it's possible to connect your Azure VM to your local domain.  The idea is that I could host the emulator on a local physical machine running Hyper-V and then attach to it from the Azure workstation VM.  Is there a fundamental reason this won't work?

- My understanding of the way the emulator works is that it gets a private IP which is then used by the debugger to attach to the device.  If this isn't correct then, never mind.

Any answers, good or bad, will be greatly appreciated.